# POST service with Datatable java

Tags: angularjs, post, datatables

I have an requirement to submit a full datatable data into database using angular js.

populating data through angularjs and code given below

```
vm.dataTableInstance = $('.datatable-basic').DataTable({
            data : priorityAttrs,
            columns : [
                       { data: 'priority', title : 'Priority', width : '10%' },
                       { data: 'attrName', title : 'Attribute Name', width: '30%' },
                       { data: null, title : 'Notes', width: '50%' ,render:function(data ,type,row){
                           return '<input type="text" id="notesInputTxt" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the note" value='+data.notes+'>';
                       }},
                       { data: null, orderable : false, width:'5%', render : function(data, type, row){
                           return '<ul class="icons-list"><li class="delete-user text-danger-600" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().deleteAttribute(this, \''+data.attrName+'\')"><a><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></li></ul>';
                       }}
                   ],
```

Now I need to take all the data from datatable using post request.Please find the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Consider using [Angular DataTables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome).

Answer (score 0):

Just extract all the data using [rows().data](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) and put it into array and then post using http.

**Angular Controller**

```
var module = angular.module('app',[]);

module.controller('Ctrl', function ($http) {

vm.dataTableInstance = $('.datatable-basic').DataTable({
            data : priorityAttrs,
            columns : [
                       { data: 'priority', title : 'Priority', width : '10%' },
                       { data: 'attrName', title : 'Attribute Name', width: '30%' },
                       { data: null, title : 'Notes', width: '50%' ,render:function(data ,type,row){
                           return '<input type="text" id="notesInputTxt" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the note" value='+data.notes+'>';
                       }},
                       { data: null, orderable : false, width:'5%', render : function(data, type, row){
                           return '<ul class="icons-list"><li class="delete-user text-danger-600" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().deleteAttribute(this, \''+data.attrName+'\')"><a><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></li></ul>';
                       }}
                   ],

var arrayData = vm.dataTableInstance.rows().data();     

 $http.post('services/api', arrayData).then(function (resp) {
       // Success
       console.log(resp.data);
 }, console.log('Error')),


});
```

Comment: when you want to populate that data? Is it during save?

Comment: First I populated the data through some GET service then I have this edit option on notes. After editing there is a save option which will take the datatable data with the edit values in it then hit some post service

Comment: I think you must find the value of textedit by find its id separately and push it into array.

Comment: Mixing jquery data tables with angularjs is problematic. You should read this https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21286/datatables-and-angularjs

Comment: So as you see in the code the columns are populated dynamically.                 { data: 'priority', title : 'Priority', width : '10%' },
                       { data: 'attrName', title : 'Attribute Name', width: '30%' },
                       { data: null, title : 'Notes', width: '50%' ,render:function(data ,type,row){
                           return '<input type="text" id="notesInputTxt" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the note" value='+data.notes+'>';                       }},

Comment: and also I need to take that priority from the each row too as these rows are having drag and drop option